# how to define MIME Type?

Tags: asp.net

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension =".wav"/>   
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".wav" mimeType="audio/wav" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />         
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

i try this code but not worked. Help me to solve it.
thanks

Comment: try this http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-can-i-define-mime-types-on-my-windowsiis-based-site

Comment: Try to explain your problem.